# Filtering dataframe to only show 1 pair of two variables

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have information on physicians working in different hospitals at different points in time. I would like to output a dataframe with that informs each pair of physician in each hospital. I would like to see each pair only once in the dataset; meaning that if physicians A and B work together in the same hospital I would like to see either the pair A-B or the pair B-A, but not both.

Consider the very simple example of hospitals x-y-w, periods 1-2 and physicians A-B-C-D.

```
mydf <- data.frame(hospital = c("x","x","x","x","x","y","y","y","w","w","w","w"), 
                period = c(1,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,2), 
                physician = c("A","B","C","A","B","A","A","C","C","D","A","D"))
```

Below I manage to get all pairs, however each pair shows twice (swapping between `from` and `to`). How could get each pair only showing up once in the output?

```
pairs_df <- mydf %>%
  rename(from = physician) %>%
  left_join(mydf, by=c("hospital","period")) %>%
  rename(to = physician) %>%
  filter(from!=to)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `pmin/pmax` with `duplicated` to sort the elements rowwise between the 'from', 'to' columns, apply the `duplicated`, negate (`!`) in `filter` to return the unique rows

```
library(dplyr)
pairs_df %>% 
     filter(!duplicated(cbind(pmax(from, to), pmin(from, to))))
```

---

Or use `base R`

```
subset(pairs_df, !duplicated(cbind(pmax(from, to), pmin(from, to))))
```

-output

```
     hospital period from to
1         x      1    A  B
2         x      1    A  C
4         x      1    B  C
11        w      1    C  D
13        w      2    A  D
```

NOTE: Here, we assume that the columns are `character` class based on the input data i.e. `data.frame` construct uses `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` by default (`>= R 4.0.0`), but previously it was `TRUE` by default.  If the columns are `factor`, then we could convert to `character` class with `type.convert`

```
pairs_df <- type.convert(pairs_df, as.is = TRUE)
```

Or before the `filter` convert those `factor` to `character`

```
pairs_df %>%
   mutate(across(where(is.factor), as.character)) %>%
   filter(!duplicated(cbind(pmax(from, to), pmin(from, to))))
```

Comment: I don't know why but your code is outputting a different result for me together with the following: `Warning messages: 
1: In Ops.factor(mmm, each) : ‘<’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(mmm, each) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors`

Comment: It is outputting the rows `1, 3, 5, 12` instead of `1, 2, 4, 11, 13`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using `igraph`

```
get.data.frame(
  simplify(
    graph_from_data_frame(
      pairs_df[c("from", "to", "hospital", "period")],
      directed = FALSE
    ),
    edge.attr.comb = "first"
  )
)
```

which gives

```
  from to hospital period
1    A  B        x      1
2    A  C        x      1
3    A  D        w      2
4    B  C        x      1
5    C  D        w      1
```